# Carbon 12 hous format

Tags: php, mysql, php-carbon

I have some dates in my DB and I want to show them in a 12 hour format with AM - PM at the end. I am using carbon, my code is this:

```
$hora = Carbon::createFromFormat('h:i A', $fecha_inicio, 'UTC')->setTimeZone($timeZone)->format('h:i A');
```

$fecha_inicio is something like **2018-11-02 13:47:03**.

But this throws an error: ** Hour can not be higher than 12**

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> h  12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    01 through 12
>
> H  24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23

So, use `H:i` instead of `h:i`

```
$hora = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $fecha_inicio, 'UTC')->setTimeZone($timeZone)->format('h:i A');
```

The first parameter from `createFromFormat` is the format you already have in `$fecha_inicio`

Comment: I did it but now I have this problem  "The separation symbol could not be found\nA meridian could not be found"

Comment: What's in `$timeZone`?

Comment: A time zone, but it doesn't affect, even if i edit that line to $hora = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $fecha_inicio, 'UTC') I have the same problem.

Comment: This code works on my machine. Unless the value of `$fecha_inicio` is in a different format than your example, or you are omitting code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the TIME in 12hr format

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($fecha_inicio)->isoFormat('h:mm:i')
```

And if you want the TIME in 24hr format

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($fecha_inicio)->isoFormat('H:MM:I')
```